# Looks like the migration bug is back

Tags: discussion, bug, status-completed, migration, vote-to-close

Attempting to migrate a question on StackOverflow fails, at the moment.

[image: lolwut?]

Example: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5794913

Cannot migrate via Close as Off Topic, or [Migrate to Any Site.](https://stackoverflow.com/error?aspxerrorpath=/admin/posts/5794913/migrate-anywhere/submit)

Comment: [Same here](http://i.imgur.com/cCfLM.png). Only migration votes seem to be affected.

Comment: Actual error: *An attempt has been made to Attach or Add an entity that is not new, perhaps having been loaded from another DataContext. This is not supported.*

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Boy is this a circuitous one.

Recently, we started auto-awarding association bonuses.  No longer will you have to disassociate/re-associate to gain a bonus, you'll get it once one account in the network passes 200 rep.

... except that when you crossed that boundary (<200 to >= 200) due to a migration things get funky*.  For now, I've disabled the auto bit of association bonuses.

<del>It'll be re-enabled once this rare case is actually fixed, probably later tonight.  I've also cleaned up the single affected post.</del>

The automatic bonus code has been fixed, and will go out with our next deploy.  Took a little longer than I'd hoped, because testing migrations is a pain; even more so when dealing with associated user accounts.

<sub>*Users from different DB contexts sitting next to each other makes things a bit funky, as a lot of our code assumes any given user is from the "Current" site/DB.</sub>